# yum remove issues during clean un-install of HDP

Tags: linux, yum, rhel, hortonworks-data-platform

As mentioned in several links like [this](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-uninstall.html) and [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Host+Cleanup+for+Ambari+and+Stack), I am trying to clean un-install Hortonworks 2.2 Data Platform.

Being naive in Linux, I am facing issues from the first step itself - removing the installed HDP packages.

```
[root@l1031lab ~]# yum list installed | grep HDP
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
bigtop-jsvc.x86_64             1.0.10.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
bigtop-tomcat.noarch           6.0.41-1.el6         @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2.x86_64        2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-client.x86_64 2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-doc.x86_64    2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-hdfs.x86_64   2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-httpfs.x86_64 2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-source.x86_64 2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hadoop_2_2_4_2_2-yarn.x86_64   2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2.noarch         0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2-doc.noarch     0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2-master.noarch  0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
                               0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2-rest.noarch    0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2-thrift.noarch  0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hbase_2_2_4_2_2-thrift2.noarch 0.98.4.2.2.4.2-2.el6 @HDP-2.2
hdp-select.noarch              2.2.4.2-2.el6        @HDP-2.2
phoenix_2_2_4_2_2.noarch       4.2.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
zookeeper_2_2_4_2_2.noarch     3.4.6.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
                               3.4.6.2.2.4.2-2.el6  @HDP-2.2
```

I am trying to remove all these packages in one go :

```
[root@l1031lab ~]# yum remove "HDP*"
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: HDP*
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.2.4.2/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.2.4.2/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/centos6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/centos6/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/updates/2.0.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/updates/2.0.0/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
No package HDP* available.
  * Maybe you meant: hdp-select, hdparm
No Packages marked for removal
```

I have two questions :

1. Is Internet connectivity the issue here ?
2. If yes, is it mandatory to have Internet for a clean removal of all these packages

Answer (score 1):

Your internet connectivity isn't the problem. The problem is that `yum` isn't able to find a package name that matches `HDP*` to remove. Yum package names are case sensitive. Based on your first link you want to run the following:

```
sudo yum remove bigtop* hbase* zookeeper* hadoop* hdp-* phoenix*
```

Edit:

The updated command will cause `yum` to expand the package names to remove any package which begins with the string, so `bigtop*` will cause `bigtop-jsvc` and `bigtop-tomcat` to be removed. The order the packages are added in doesn't matter as `yum` is clever enough to deal with dependencies etc.

Comment: My objective is to cleanly remove pkg(and dependents as yum does) that are displayed after the yum list installed | grep HDP. How do I remove these in one go ? Or is it that I have to list them individually ? In that case, does the order(I don't know their interdependence) matter ?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, the single `yum` command I've shown will remove everything you've listed by `yum list installed | grep HDP`. As I've said the order doesn't matter as `yum` will cleanly deal with the dependencies etc.

Answer (score -2):

There you go! Here's the solution to your problem. I struggled with this for like weeks and tried uninstalling and reinstalling over and over and then finally decided to share it here : [How to completely remove and uninstall hadoop componens](http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/how-to-completely-remove-and-uninstall-hdp-components-hadoop-uninstall-on-linux-system/)

The trick is to basically delete all the symlinks pointing back to locations where HDP components reside since that is what causes 80% of the problem.